# The Bodyguard hotel kitchen scene

Tags: plot-explanation, the-bodyguard

In The Bodyguard, why does Costner go into the kitchen of the Miami hotel?  Why is he so agitated when he sees a stack of boxes, looking for a Louis Gomez, and beats up the Cuban on a smoke break?

Answer (score 4):

Frank Farmer (Kevin Costner) is very thorough when he is protecting somebody.  He is constantly working with Rachel Marron's (Whitney Houston) current staff on security protocols.

Frank goes into the kitchen of the Miami hotel to do a security check and to ensure that there is always a safe exit strategy if they need to leave the hotel through the back entrance at any point.

Frank and Rachel have already been romantically involved at this point and they had just had an argument before Frank checked the route through the kitchen.  Frank was already agitated because of this argument and took out his frustrations on the kitchen staff that happened to be there at that time.
Frank had obviously had a previous arrangement with Louis Gomez to keep certain areas of the kitchen uncluttered so a safe exit plan could be made.  The man that Frank encounters in the kitchen agitated Frank even more and he lost his temper and physically assaults him.

The fact that he was Cuban had nothing to do with it.